# Facebook SDK validating user

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

as many i have little trouble with the IOS Facebook SDK.

I'm creating application that have my own login process and facebook login.
In my application, i have an section that you can buy products, and i want to validate
That the person that holding the iPhone is the real user before letting him to make purchases.
If a user is logged in the regular way, all i need to do is to ask the user to re-enter his password and compare it to the real password.
How can i do the same when loggin with facebook? let's when clicking the "Pay" button
i call "closeAndClearTokenInformation" and close the session, when i ask to re-open the session, it to the app switching process and re-open the session without user interaction.

It seems like i have no way to ask the SDK to really authenticate (re-login) the user to facebook. am i right?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct way to do what you're asking for, but there is a workaround, and you don't even need to call closeAndClearTokenInformation on your existing session.

You can create a new FBSession with the login behavior of FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView, open that session (which should force the user to log in via a webview). You can then make a /me request with the new session, and compare it to the user id in your existing session.

Comment: Good thinking! but i think that FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView may open the webview with the last fbsession without user interaction.
I mean that if i'm logged in in the browser and in the IOS with the same facebook user, It might not require the user interaction to revalidate his password/account. all it will do is to check that the browser fbuser is the same as my current fbuser. i'll check it later on